# Pandas: Index Not Preserved when performing Groupby Rolling on Datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where some dates are the same. As an illustration of the problem, I have created a sample df with dates all the same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": range(6), 
                   "column2": range(6), 
                   'group': 3*['A','B'], 
                   'date':pd.date_range("20190101", periods=6)})
df.loc[:,'date']=df.loc[0,'date']

df
# Output of DF
   column1  column2 group       date
0        0        0     A 2019-01-01
1        1        1     B 2019-01-01
2        2        2     A 2019-01-01
3        3        3     B 2019-01-01
4        4        4     A 2019-01-01
5        5        5     B 2019-01-01
```

The problem occurs when performing a groupby rolling operation on datetime column: the index is not preserved. This is a problem when the dates are the same as there is no way of being able to merge back onto the original dataframe (which is what I am aiming for).

```
df.groupby('group').rolling('2D',on='date')['column1'].sum()

# Output of Groupby Rolling
group  date      
A      2019-01-01    0.0
       2019-01-01    2.0
       2019-01-01    6.0
B      2019-01-01    1.0
       2019-01-01    4.0
       2019-01-01    9.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

I have an alternative solution that works, however it is considerably slower.

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.rolling('2D',on='date')['column1'].sum())

# Output of Groupby Apply Rolling 
group   
A      0    0.0
       2    2.0
       4    6.0
B      1    1.0
       3    4.0
       5    9.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

Hoping for something more efficient than the above.

Comment: I would first sort `df` by group and date, then do the same groupby wirh a `.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end, finally assign that series to df

Comment: NOTE: that this line of code: `pd.date_range("20190101", periods=6)})` will not output six dates with `2019-01-01` as their values. It will output six dates with `2019-01-01` and `2019-01-02`, etc. So, in my answer, I just changed to `.rolling('5D'` to get the same output.

Comment: NOTE: look carefully. There was already a line to include this `df.loc[:,'date']=df.loc[0,'date']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I have created a more complex sample df to test the efficiency of each solution proposed above.

My original approach (slowest here, but efficient if there are very few groups):

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": range(600), 
                   "column2": range(600), 
                   "column3": range(600),
                   "column4": range(600),
                   "column5": range(600),
                   "column6": range(600),
                   "column7": range(600),
                   "column8": range(600),
                   'group': 5*['l'+str(i) for i in range(120)], 
                   'date':pd.date_range("20190101", periods=600)})

### Set the date the same
df.loc[:,'date']=df.loc[0,'date']

cols = ['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5','column6','column7','column8']
newcols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8']
if newcols[0] not in df.columns:
    df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+newcols)

df[newcols]=df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.rolling('2D',on='date')[cols].sum()
                                     ).sort_index(level=1).drop('date',axis=1).values

# timeit output
345 ms ± 28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

David Erikson's solution. It is efficient if there are many groups with a small number of observations within each group.

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": range(600), 
                   "column2": range(600), 
                   "column3": range(600),
                   "column4": range(600),
                   "column5": range(600),
                   "column6": range(600),
                   "column7": range(600),
                   "column8": range(600),
                   'group': 5*['l'+str(i) for i in range(120)], 
                   'date':pd.date_range("20190101", periods=600)})

### Set the date the same
df.loc[:,'date']=df.loc[0,'date']

cols = ['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5','column6','column7','column8']
newcols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8']
if newcols[0] not in df.columns:
    df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+newcols)

my_dict = {}
my_dict["index"] = "max"
my_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(cols, "sum"))
df[newcols]=df.reset_index().groupby('group').rolling('2D',
on='date').agg(my_dict).sort_values('index').drop('index',axis=1).values

# timeit output
110 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

RichieV's proposed solution which is the fastest here:

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": range(600), 
                   "column2": range(600), 
                   "column3": range(600),
                   "column4": range(600),
                   "column5": range(600),
                   "column6": range(600),
                   "column7": range(600),
                   "column8": range(600),
                   'group': 5*['l'+str(i) for i in range(120)], 
                   'date':pd.date_range("20190101", periods=600)})

### Set the date the same
df.loc[:,'date']=df.loc[0,'date']

cols = ['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5','column6','column7','column8']
newcols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8']
if newcols[0] not in df.columns:
    df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+newcols)
    
df=df.sort_values(['group','date'],kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
df[newcols]=df.groupby('group').rolling('2D',on='date')[cols].sum().values
df=df.sort_values('column1',kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)

# timeit output
40 ms ± 6.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reset_index()` and then include that `index` column as a resull of the rest with `.groupby` and `.agg`. I imagine this will be much faster than lambda x.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": range(6), 
               "column2": range(6), 
               'group': 3*['A','B'], 
               'date':pd.date_range("20190101", periods=6)})
df = df.reset_index().groupby('group').rolling('5D',on='date').agg({'index' : 'max', 'column1' : 'sum'}))

df

                   index    column1
group   date        
A       2019-01-01  0.0     0.0
        2019-01-03  2.0     2.0
        2019-01-05  4.0     6.0
B       2019-01-02  1.0     1.0
        2019-01-04  3.0     4.0
        2019-01-06  5.0     9.0
```

From there, if you want the format of the final output without the date, you can do:

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['group','index'])['column1'].sum()

group  index
A      0.0      0.0
       2.0      2.0
       4.0      6.0
B      1.0      1.0
       3.0      4.0
       5.0      9.0
```